# Add a node to XML using Nokogiri::XML::Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a `Nokogiri::XML::Builder` instance, when I call `to_xml` it produces following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item>...</item>
  <item>...</item>
</root>
```

Using this instance I'd like to add one more `<item>` node under `<root>` like this:

```
def add_static_job(builder)
  source = builder.doc.root
  item =  Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('item', source)
  item.content = '<title>Hello</title>'
  source << item
end
```

Unfortunatelly this doesn't produce valid xml in the end, rather something like:

```
<item>&lt;title&gt;Hello&lt;title&gt;</item>
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in 2 steps :

- create title node with "Hello" as content
- create item node with title as content

---

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <item>A</item>
  <item>B</item>
</root>'

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)

source = doc.root

title = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('title', doc)
title.content = "Hello"

item  = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('item', doc)
item << title

source << item

puts doc

# =>
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
# <root>
#   <item>A</item>
#   <item>B</item>
# <item><title>Hello</title></item></root>
```